# How do I chain methods in classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, chain

This is the task I need to complete:

Consider that you are interested in coloured shapes on paper. Write a class 'Shape'which has a hidden attribute of colour, an access method to get the colour (you may wish to have a default colour) and an modifier method to set the colour.

Try and make it so that you can chain your methods, e.g.

```
s = Shape()
s.set('Red').colour()
Output: Red

s.set('Yellow').set('Blue').colour()
Output: Yellow
```

I'm very new to python, and im lost. This is what I already have and it's probably really wrong. I would appreciate some help.

This is what I already have:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, colour = None):
        self._colour = colour
        
    def colour(self):
        print(self._colour)
        
    def set(self, new_colour):
        self.new_colour = new_colour
        self._colour = new_colour
        
s = Shape()
```

but it doesn't seem to work the way the task wants it to. please help.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I think that what you show of your code and how you use it that there are no problems.

Comment: Return `self` in `set()`? Or return `Shape(new_colour)`.

Comment: The task seems strange to me. In general, order of operations would suggest that `s.set('Yellow').set('Blue').colour()` outputs `Blue`. My mental map says that Yellow is set first, then Blue overwrites it.

Comment: Just to mention that there is no need for setters and getters at all. I understand that this is assignment, but it's a stupid one.

Answer (score 0):

If you return self in the set method this will work. This is because you are calling `.set()` on the shape class, and if `.set()` does not return the object it belongs to, you are calling `.set()` on nothing.

Comment: To be precise, if the method/function doesn't return anything explicitly, it'll return `None`. So OP is calling `.set()` on `None`

Answer (score 0):

**Return self in the set() method**

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, colour=None):
        self._colour = colour

    def colour(self):
        print(self._colour)


    def set(self, new_colour):
        self.new_colour = new_colour
        self._colour = new_colour
        return self
```

Answer (score 0):

You chain methods by having one method return an object that has the next method(s) of interest. Frequently, that's the `self` object - allowing the programmer to call another method on that class.

But method chaining happens all over the place because *all* return values are objects with methods. For instance,

```
s = " ABC "
s_lowered = s.strip().lower()
```

In your case

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, colour = None):
        self._colour = colour
        
    def colour(self):
        print(self._colour)
        return self
        
    def set(self, new_colour):
        self.new_colour = new_colour
        self._colour = new_colour
        return self

s = Shape()
s.set('Red').colour()
s.set('Yellow').set('Blue').colour()
```

`s.set()` returns an unnamed reference to the `s` object which is used for the next `.colour()` call. That call returned another unnamed reference to the same `s` object, but since you don't assign it to anything, python discards it.